# Relationship between i.o., eventually, liminf, and limsup when P sigma-finite

Tags: probability-theory

I am reading about some assumptions related to the Borel-Cantelli Lemmas.

I see that:

$P(A_{n}$ i.o.$ ) \geq limsupP(A_{n})$,

and $P(A_{n}$ eventually$) \leq lim infP(A_{n})$

Would both of these inequalities hold if P is only assumed to be $\sigma$-finite?

Answer (score 1):

For sigma finite measures the first one is false and the second one is true. For the first one consider $I_{(n,n+1)}$ in the real line with Lebesgue measure.

The second one is true for any measure and it is just special case of Fatou's Lemma.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically Fatou's lemma (both the basic version and the dominated version). You're asking whether or not the following two inequalities hold: $$\int \liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}1_{A_n}\,dP\le \liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}\int 1_{A_n}\,dP\\ \limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\int 1_{A_n}\,dP\le \int\limsup_{n\to\infty} 1_{A_n}\,dP$$

The short answer is that the $\liminf$-inequality always holds in any measure space. The $\limsup$-inequality holds whenever the sequence $1_{A_n}$ is dominated by a $L^1$ function: namely, if there is a subset $A$ of finite measure such that eventually $A_n\subseteq A$.